# Does "living in squalor" necessarily imply poverty?

Tags: meaning, connotation

Some definitions of *squalor* and its adjectival form *squalid*:

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squalor)

> *squalor*: the quality or state of being squalid
>   *squalid*: marked by filthiness and degradation from neglect or poverty

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/squalor)

> *squalor*: the condition or quality of being squalid; disgusting dirt and filth
>   *squalid*: dirty and repulsive, esp as a result of neglect or poverty

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/squalor?rdfrom=Squalor)

> *squalor*: Squalidness; foulness; filthiness; squalidity.
>   *squalid*: Extremely dirty and unpleasant

[Compact Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/squalor?view=uk)

> *squalor*: the state of being extremely dirty and unpleasant, especially as a result of poverty or neglect
>   *squalid*: (of a place) extremely dirty and unpleasant, especially as a result of poverty or neglect

(Ok, now that y’all are suffering from the same word glare/semantic satiation as I am …)

If someone is described as *living in squalor*, does that automatically imply that they’re doing so because they’re too poor to do otherwise? I know that context can override the usual connotation of words, so for example if I’ve established that someone is a reclusive millionaire, the fact that she’s living in squalor would not necessarily be a contradiction. But if I encounter this phrase on its own, am I wrong to assume poverty?

Comment: College students are sometimes said to be living in squalor. Has more to do with the mountains of dirty clothes and empty liquor bottles than lack of funds.

Comment: General Reference. From a recent newspaper report into the death of Eva Rausing (one of Britain’s richest women) - [The friend, who did not want to be named, said: "It was total **squalor**. Really messy. You wouldn't believe they were billionaires.](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/crime/9395338/Police-piece-together-heiress-Eva-Rausings-final-days.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are wrong to assume poverty, but I suspect it's what many of us might do.

Comment: Barrie: I'm with you. I might say it's wrong to assume poverty every time, but there's nothing wrong with assuming it as the general case.  Collins made that distinction rather nicely.

Answer (score 18):

By the definitions that you provided above, and my own interpretation, "Living in squalor" does *not* directly imply poverty. It could just as easily be neglect. For example, if someone of moderate means is a hoarder, they could easily be living in squalor.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the above definitions, you  would be right to assume that the term *squalor* is automatically associated with the word *poverty*. One can be financially rich while living in spiritual, emotional, or psychological poverty. Something is severely lacking when a person lives in  squalor.